# rails request spec PUT method with json doesn't go through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec-rails

In one of my tests I have to verify that a certain offer returns 404 response if the available limit (10 seats for example with that offer) are all sold, or it has expired which ever comes first.

I just cannot get the PUT request to work in Request Spec, here's my code

```
RSpec.describe "Offers", type: :request do
  describe "gives not found response" do

    it "when available limit exhausts before date till available" do
        offer = Offer.new
        Timecop.freeze(Date.today - 12.days) do
            offer = FactoryGirl.create(:offer)
        end
        payload = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:offer, :available_limit => 0, :discount_id => offer.discount.id, :coupon_id => offer.coupon.id)
        sign_in
        put '/offers/'<<offer.id, params: { id: offer.id, offer: payload }, as: :json
        get "/vouchers/"<<offer.coupon.voucher_code
        expect(response.status).to eq 404
    end
  end
end
```

needles to say that I have tried many hacks including

```
put '/offers/'<<offer.id.to_s<<".json", params: { offer: payload }
```

or even

```
put '/offers/'<<offer.id.to_s<<".json", payload
```

What I also noticed was that in one of the combinations the request did go through but it responds with both HTML and JSON format which lead to error in the spec as I am not running them under capybara (and I do not want to either)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<<` to build those paths. Using `<<` with an id will insert a character code equivalent to the integer value of the id, e.g.

```
'XYZ' << 123 << 'ABC'
 => "XYZ{ABC"
```

Just use normal string interpolation, e.g.

```
put "/offers/#{offer.id}", params: { id: offer.id, offer: payload }, format: :json
get "/vouchers/#{offer.coupon.voucher_code}"
```

Credit to @house9 for noticing the `format: :json` part as well.

Comment: the latest stable branch for integration tests shows all action dispatch integration methods refer to a process method, where the signature has `as: :son` instead of format, here's the link https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0a4d1c3cdeaf387b4cb4288462084c8ee1a9b039/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L33

Comment: `put "/offers/#{offer.id}", params: { id: offer.id, offer: payload }, as: :json` that worked well!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `format: :json` not `as: :json`

Try:

```
params = { id: offer.id, offer: payload }
put :offers, params: params, format: :json
```

Comment: `format: :json` has been changed to `as: :json` in recent versions, I don't think it is breaking because of that